# Save As in MS Office for Mac to a different location

Tags: ms-office

I have Office for Mac 2011 which seems to work OK. However if I open a file from one location and wish to do Save As.. to another location, all I get is the basic list of where I can save, but seemingly no opportunity to drill down into sub-folders etc. For instance in the screen shot the location Kingston is an external usb drive with multiple folders and sub folders, but if I click on that, it puts that into the Where box and the document is saved in the root of that. Any ideas please, Gurus?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

If you click on the little triangle to the right of the Save As box it will open more detailed window to choose where to save it. OS X has both a simple and expanded Save dialog and applications can choose to show one or the other as the default Save dialog. Looks like MS Office defaults to the simplified view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click on the down arrow button next to the file name you specify. You should get a window to select the location where you want to save the file.